# Selenium: check textarea is cleared on click

Tags: python, html, selenium, textarea

I'm using selenium with Python.
I'm writing a functional test in which I want to check that when a user clicks on a textarea, it clears its content.

This is the HTML code for the text area:

```
<textarea id="id_textarea" cols="50" rows="10" onclick="this.value=''">Enter some text</textarea>
```

It works in my browser but I can't get it working with selenium and my test fails over and over again.
This is my Python code:

```
# User clicks on the text area which removes its content.
input_textarea.click()
self.assertEqual(input_textarea.text, '')
```

Note that my point is not to use the selenium `input_textarea.clear()` function as I precisely want to check that the HTML code handles this part.

Any help would be appreciated.

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `get_attribute('value')` method instead of `text`:

```
input_textarea.click()
self.assertEqual(input_textarea.get_attribute('value'), '')
```

P.S. I assume that `input_textarea` is something like `driver.find_element_by_id('id_textarea')`

Comment: Totally works! Thanks. Would you please enlighten me and tell me why I can't use `text` and when I should use it?

Comment: @binoua text is for the text within the tags of an element, whereas the text you're looking for is not inside the <input> tags. Therefore you need to use value.